# Deploying React application with Node server behind Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have a MERN stack application that I have created. I have managed to get the application deployed to AWS fine. I use `pm2 start index.js` in the `server/` folder which is listening on `port 5000`, and then in the `client/` folder, I run `pm2 start --name myapp npm -- start`, which is running on `port 3000`.

This works well because if I go to my ec2 instance public URL with the port, my application is there. For example purpose, let's say it's `5.121.15.32:3000` (its not actually).

I then want to use `nginx` to not only remove the port, but also point to my domain which is setup to point to my ec2 instance. So then, on my ec2 server, I run `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.online mydomain.online;
    root /home/ubuntu/my_app/client/build;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Here is my `package.json` in my `clients/` folder:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-date-picker": "^9.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^2.7.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

`server/index.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const connection = require("./db");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");

const dashboardRoutes = require("./routes/dashboard");

// database connection
connection();

// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// routes
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/dashboard", dashboardRoutes);


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

`client/App.js`

```
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Login from "./components/Login";


function App() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem("token");

    return (
        <Routes>
            {user && <Route path="/dashboard/:_id" exact element={<Main />} />}

            <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login />} />

            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`cd /home/ubuntu/my_app/client/build` `ls -la`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 12 02:53 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 11 16:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  369 Mar 12 02:53 asset-manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3870 Mar 12 02:53 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  963 Mar 12 02:53 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 5347 Mar 12 02:53 logo192.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 9664 Mar 12 02:53 logo512.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  492 Mar 12 02:53 manifest.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   67 Mar 12 02:53 robots.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 12 02:53 static
```

However, when I go to `http://mydomain.online`, it shows `Cannot GET /`. The last step in my deployment is somehow pointing my ec2 instance to my domain using nginx, which I am really struggling to do. Can someone help?

Comment: I am not too sure how to verify this... Would you like for me to include one of my React files in the question? If so, which one? I would be more than happy to share any information you require. @ZacAnger

Comment: Sorry, I reread and moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: please see comments and the chat at the bottom of the comments for many more details. The question was edited a few times with updates which make segments of my answer irrelevant.

Your Nginx config only has the server (port 5000), but not the client. You need to proxy to both, and you'll need separate locations. This means you'll also have to adjust your client code to hit the server at a different path in production. This means you can close off 3000 and 5000 from public access, and avoid hardcoding the IP address. And using localhost/0.0.0.0 wouldn't work at all, since those would reference the client machine.

Additionally (from the comments) you're running Webpack Dev Server, which should not be used in prod. Instead, build the files, poi

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.online www.mydomain.online;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        # other directives here
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        # other directives here
    }
}
```

Edit based on comments: `react-scripts start` runs Webpack Dev Server, which means you'd need a method to change `allowedHosts` (see comments below), or to build the app and serve it statically (recommended). This also means no code changes to the apps.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.online www.mydomain.online;

    location / {
        root /home/ubuntu/my_app/client/build;
        # any other directives
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # any other directives
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your method of thinking. However, I implemented this and when i go to `http://mydomain.online` it returns `Invalid Host header`

Comment: Are you running webpack dev server?  That error sounds like it's coming from Webpack or some other Node server, not Nginx. If so, check out [this section of the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts) (and also don't use WDS in prod).

Comment: I am not running a webpack dev server... I have a `package.json` file that has my `proxy` in it, but apart from that, I have `pm2` and that's it. Again, if you would like for me to share any of my files, please let me know which ones and I will.

Comment: Could you add the client's package.json? Or at least the `start` script?

Comment: I have now added that in!

Comment: Okay so you are using Webpack Dev Server, that's what `react-scripts start` is. That's only meant for use in dev really, not prod — the CRA template and react-scripts expect you to run `npm run build` and then serve static files, not use WDS for serving in prod. Three options: (specify a HOST in an env file in the client](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy), run `npm run eject` so you can edit the Webpack config, or (what is generally recommended for running in prod):

Comment: `npm run build` and serve the static files from your Node app or Nginx (using a `root /path/to/files` in a location).

Comment: Okay, I am going to try add in ‘root /home/ubuntu/my_app/client/build’ below the ‘server_name’. I had this in my previous Nginx script in the question

Comment: Ah yes, I'll update my answer with that change as well. I removed that part because I thought it was a requirement to serve your client app with PM2, making that `root` useless.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with the updated `nginx` script. However, now I am getting: `Invalid Host header`. Could that have to do with all the directives I have put in my `location` (you can see them in the updated `nginx` script in the question.

Comment: See my update on my answer. If you're building static files and not running WDS, no need to proxy to 3000, you can proxy to 5000 at `/` and remove the whole 3000 location block. And also `pm2 stop myapp` since you don't need to waste resources on running `react-scripts start`.

Comment: Here is what I have done: `pm2 kill`. `cd ~/my_app/server` `pm2 start index.js`. I then added your script to `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. Ran `sudo service nginx restart` and `pm2 reload 0`. Those are the only changes I made. I now get the error `Cannot GET /` again....

Comment: StackOverflow is going to yell at us to go into a chat at any minute (too many comments), but `Cannot GET /` comes from Node most likely, Nginx's error says "404 Not Found" with "nginx" at the bottom. So that's probably saying you don't have any routes available at `/` from your node server, and don't have an `index.html` in the directory pointed to in the `root` directive. You could verify by checking the headers on the response to see if they come from your server. Is your repo public, or if not can you add a simplified version of your Node server and an `ls` of that build dir?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not let me move this to chat as I do not have enough reputation... The repo is private. However, I will update the question with the `ls` of the build dir, as well as a simplified version of my `server/index.js` file for you.

Comment: Please find the information under "Update" in the question.

Comment: You don't have any routes at `"/"` in the Express server. If you load `/api/dashboard` that should give you some other response (whatever's in that route code). I would also move the root into a location and add `api` back to the server's location — I removed those from my edited version for simplification, but having `root` above a location `/` is confusing, and I'm honestly not sure how Nginx decides which takes precedence since `/` is last-resort. Updated the second example in my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Do I need that though....? I have now updated my question to include `client/App.js` which shows that when the user goes to `/`, it reroutes to the `Login` component. I'm not really too sure if that's relevant though, just trying to provide all the information possible.

Comment: Now if I use the updated script, I get 403 Forbidden nginx error

Comment: If you upvote my question I should then have enough reputation to move this to a chat haha

Comment: Are permissions correct? Should be 755 for directories and at least 644 for files in the build directory (and its parents). `chmod -R 755 /home`. Of course that's not always desirable so for a situation where you might have sensitive data, you would want to move the build dir to `/var/www/html` or some other place that's only intended for Nginx's uage, then you could use `sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html` (assuming those are the correct username and group)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252463/discussion-between-sfhasfasf-and-zac-anger).